# How to compare user inputs with 2 different tables

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form which takes in the values of First Name, Last Name and DOB. I have two tables: TableA and TableB. Each table may contain information of the person name that is entered in the form. What I would like to do, in ColdFusion, write a query where I take the user inputs and compare which Table contains the info. Once I find which table contains the user info, display particular columns that pertain in that table.

Below is the form:

```
<Form name="ERHospital" Method="Post" class="a">

  <div align="center" style="margin-top:10pt; margin-bottom:10pt">

    <table Border="0" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 >
        <tr>
            <td class="m" id="fName">First Name&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input class="a" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="<cfoutput></cfoutput>" size="15"> 
            </td>
            <td class="m" id="lName">Last Name&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input class="a" id="LastName" name="LastName" value="<cfoutput></cfoutput>" size="15"> 
            </td>

            <td class="m" id="DOB">
                DOB<br />
                <font color="##CC0000" size="1" style="italic">(mm/dd/yyyy)</font>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="BirthDt" name ="BirthDt" id="BirthDt" maxlength="10" size="10">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!---<td class="m" id="Hospital">Hospital</td>
            <td>
                <select name="hosp" id="hosp"></select>
            </td>--->
            <!---<td class="m" colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="m">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="SubmitMe(); checkFields();" name="SubmitEmpBtn" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold">
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input type="button" name="Clear"  value="Clear" onClick="ClearForm()" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold"> 
            </td>  
        </tr>--->
    </table>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:15pt"><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="SubmitMe(); checkFields();" name="SubmitEmpBtn" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold"> <input type="button" name="Clear"  value="Clear" onClick="ClearForm()" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:bold"> </div>
   <!---<table align="center">
                <TR>
                  <TD align="center"><input type="button" value=" Submit " onClick="SubmitMe()" name="SubmitEmpBtn" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> <input type="button" name="Clear"  value=" Clear " onClick="ClearForm()" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> </td>   
                </tr>
            </table>

  </table>--->

   </div>
</FORM>
```

Comment: What database are you using? Is the person guaranteed to be only in one table? And if not, what if they are in both?

Comment: @Shawn: Database: SQL and yes, person is guaranteed to be only in one table.

Comment: SQL is a language. What is the name of the database you are using? Something like MS SQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB.....

Comment: @Shawn: I am using Ms SQL

Comment: Why are users in multiple tables? Just wondering about the db design... Also, this is a mostly a style preference, using a single set of `<cfoutput>` tags around a block of code with multiple variables is more readable than using individual tags every time you wish to display a variable, ie `<input value="<cfoutput>#var1#</cfoutput>"> ... <input value="<cfoutput>#var2#</cfoutput>>`

Comment: One of the things I've always gone by when working with CF is that pretty much everything between `cfoutput` tags gets handled by the CF server. It's super micro-optimization, but I've always preferred making the stuff in my `cfoutput` blocks as skinny as possible. Putting it around just what you need CF to handle also prevents accidental errors when you have a `<font color=#red...` inside of a `cfoutput` block. Or worse, when you `cfinclude` another page that has inline CSS inside your `cfoutput`. But I agree that it is completely a style preference.

Comment: @Ageax: Regarding your question, my boss created two different tables and according to him, "there are differences in data that requires two different tables".

Comment: It is a balance. Narrow scope is good, but sometimes one or two outputs is more readable than 25+ separate cfoutputs. Especially when the tags are nested in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

If the user is guaranteed to be in only one table, then you can use a `UNION ALL` like the following:

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasourse="#myDSN#">
    SELECT <userField1>, <userField2>
    FROM Table1
    WHERE 
        FirstName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.firstname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND
        LastName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.lastname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">

    UNION ALL

    SELECT <userField1>,<userField2>
    FROM Table2
    WHERE 
        FirstName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.firstname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND
        LastName = <cfqueryparam value="#form.lastname#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
```

If the user is only in one table, you'll only get the results for your requested user.

**EDIT:** I would also add that I am not a big fan of using form, url or any other external variable in a sql query without making sure they have been sanitized. But that is a *WHOLE* different type of discussion. :-)

Comment: A little new doing queries but if I understand the example you provided, it will check the first table, which in this case table1. If the user info is in there, display the info. Otherwsie, check table2 correct

Comment: It will check both tables essentially at the same time. But since only one has the record, that's what's returned. I will say that one of the best skills I learned as a developer was how to ask my database for the data I wanted. Databases are made for working with the data. They aren't there just to hold stuff. It's sometimes pretty amazing how much simpler some things are to do in SQL vs bring a bunch of data back to code to work with it. It's another tool to put in your toolbox.